# 3DES encryption result in iOS is not same as php?

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I try to encrypt data in iOS just like php code below:

```
<?php
    $plaintext = "test";
    $key = "12345";
    $data = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)); 
    echo ($data);
?>
```

result from above php code is `ZjMSIze/V+A=`.

I use code below for data encryption in iOS:

```
- (NSData*)encrypt3DES:(NSData*)plainData key:(NSString*)key
{
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    plainTextBufferSize = [plainData length];
    vplainText = (const void *)[plainData bytes];

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    // uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    // memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    //    NSString *key = @"123456789012345678901234";
    NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                       vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                       vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);
    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) NSLog( @"PARAM ERROR");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) NSLog( @"BUFFER TOO SMALL");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) NSLog( @"MEMORY FAILURE");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) NSLog( @"ALIGNMENT");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) NSLog( @"DECODE ERROR");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) NSLog( @"UNIMPLEMENTED");

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];

    return myData;
}

NSData *encrpyData = [self encrypt3DES:[@"test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] key:@"12345"];
NSLog(@"%@", [encrpyData base64Encoding]);
```

the result of data encryption in iOS is `ZjdeIS8NijE=` which is not the same as php.

How should I do to make iOS encryption function return same result as php?

Comment: In addition to the answer I gave below, here's some general advice: Learn the basics of encryption before trying to code it. If you don't know the difference between a block cipher and a stream cipher, or how CBC mode works and why it's better than ECB mode (what you're using), then slowly step away from the encryption.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I am very new to data encryption. Now I must learn more about them because my client started requiring me to encrypt data before sending to their API for security reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Obj-C code in the `CCCode` call you lie to the compiler and say that your key is `kCCKeySize3DES` bytes long even though it's really only 5. 3DES requires a 24 byte key.

So what is happening is that it's reading whatever garbage happens to be in memory after the 5 bytes of your key as the rest of the key. Who knows what that is, and that is why the encryption result is different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I change my key to 24 byte but the encryption result still have a little difference between iOS and php. Then I decrypt result from PHP by using iOS code and log NSData to find the difference. I found that php have more byte than iOS so I add this code in encryption function `NSMutableData *appendData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:plainData];[appendData appendBytes:"\0" length:3];` and it work like magic. May be it about padding algorithm between iOS and php.

Comment: Yes, again you should learn the basics of encryption before using it. Block ciphers (like DES) require the input to be a multiple of the block length (8 in the case of DES). Various padding schemes exist to make sure that happens. Your iOS code uses PKCS7 padding. Read the documentation for your PHP library and you'll probably be able to get it to use PKCS7 padding as well.